# How to make infinite rotation of image with vue-kinesis?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `vue-kinesis` to animate an image, my component below works fine, but the animation is actually done with css directly. How should I change my configuration to make `vue-kinesis` manage the rotation ?

Also, how to configure `vue-kinesis` globally in `nuxt.config.js` ?

```
<template>
  <kinesis-container>
    <kinesis-element type="depth" :strength="20">
      <v-img class="mb-5 image" src="/my-image.png" alt="Cell" />
    </kinesis-element>
  </kinesis-container>
</template>
<script>
import { KinesisContainer, KinesisElement } from 'vue-kinesis'
export default {
  components: {
    KinesisContainer,
    KinesisElement,
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.image {
  -webkit-animation: spin 180s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 180s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 180s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: On top of my answer, I was wondering why don't you want to keep CSS animation since it's easy to setup and works as intended in your case. Want to have more control of the rotation?

Comment: @kissu I wanted to use `vue-kinesis` the right way. But I might stick on it to keep both rotation and the effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PS: it looks like setting an animation without a mouse-over is not possible tho: https://github.com/Aminerman/vue-kinesis/issues/47#issuecomment-731059233
So you should rather stick to CSS rotations or use GSAP/alike.

---

I made you a project that you can find here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-vue-kinesis-00c4t?file=/pages/index.vue

The config was pretty basic, it's following the [official way](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins) of importing plugins and working perfectly.

Drop `plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/vue-kinesis.js', mode: 'client' }],` into your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Drop this in `plugins/vue-kinesis.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueKinesis from 'vue-kinesis'

Vue.use(VueKinesis)
```

And call your kinesis into your component, no need to import anything since we do have the [`components`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-components) config property now !

The template comes down to

```html
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <kinesis-container>
      <kinesis-element type="rotate" :strength="20">
        <v-img
          class="mb-5 image"
          src="https://source.unsplash.com/500x350/?japan"
          alt="Cell"
        />
      </kinesis-element>
    </kinesis-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The rotation in your example just has one loop and works when passing the mouse through. How do you make it start automatically and infinite ?